# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils' . even though I have install imutils

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have already installed imutils by using both methods pip install as well as pip3 install. but still, it is showing the same error while importing the module. The error says that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils' "

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTDw8.png)

please help as my project deadline is near.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run:

```
pip install –upgrade imutils
```

Comment: this did'nt help. I tried this but thanks for the answer. maybe there was some problem with jupyter notebook.
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'imutils'])
this command in jupyter notebook helped. If you know can you please tell me the meaning of this command.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pip  
pip.main(['install', 'imutils'])
```

this worked for me in jupyter notebook. this method I found in pythonfixing.com . I dont know what it means. If someone knows what this command means please tell me.
But after executing this command in jupyter notebook, I was able to import the installed imutils in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that you've not installed the module at the correct location. Make sure the path is correct where the module is getting installed. The modules should be installed in the `Scripts` folder with pip using cmd. Investigate the file path and try again. Your code should work